# Arduino Millis on the LCD

Tags: networking, port, router, arduino-uno, dhcp

I want to display the millis on the LCD 16x2, but the problem is that counter does not start from zero after I have added MySQL insert code. Actually, sometimes the connection to the server starts after 4 sec, 40 sec, and sometimes 79 sec.

The type of Arduino I am using is: "Arduino Uno",
and Arduino IDE Version is 1.6.7.

Could anyone help me to fix this problem, and here is the code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server_addr();  // IP of the MySQL *server* here

char user[] = "";              // MySQL user login username
char password[] = "";        // MySQL user login password


EthernetClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup() {

 // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
lcd.begin(16, 2);

// Print a message to the LCD.
lcd.print("Millis");

Serial.begin(115200);
while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect
Ethernet.begin(mac_addr);
Serial.println("Connecting...");
if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)) {
delay(1000);
}

else
Serial.println("Connection failed.");  
}


void loop() {

unsigned long var =(millis()/1000);

if(var%40 == 0)
{

char INSERT_SQL[] = "UPDATE Information.total SET reading=(%d) WHERE 
Name='Sam';";
char query[255];
sprintf(query, INSERT_SQL, var);
MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
cur_mem->execute(query);

delete cur_mem;

}  

lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
lcd.print(var);

}
```

ِAnd, here is the other code in which the millis start from Zero (Before inserting MySQL insert code):

```
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

 LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

 void setup() {
 lcd.begin(16, 2);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 lcd.print("Millis");

 }

 void loop() {
 unsigned long var =(millis()/1000);
 var = (var==0)?1:var;
 if(var%40 == 0)
 {
 Serial.println("Millis: ");
 Serial.println(var);
  }  
 lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
 lcd.print(millis()/1000);
 delay(1000);
 }
```

All answers are appreciated…

Comment: Could you edit your post by including the code that starts from zero?

Comment: Are you trying to update the database every 40 milliseconds?

Comment: Could you get the millis to display and did it start from zero everytime or at least with the time elapsed since you started the displaying?

Comment: @Blurry Sterk, actually it starts based on the time elapsed and the time elapsed is based on the connection to the server at the same time. So, if the connection to the server starts after 30 sec then even the millis will start from 30.

Answer (score 0):

Millis is the number of milliseconds since that program started on the arduino

I would be surprised if it's ever zero (unless is rolled over)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, actually it was fine before and stars from zero.

Comment: @Someone, this answer does not provide a solution for the issue addressed in the question. Please, consider to elaborate more your answer. Otherwise, a comment would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Someone, I am trying to send the value for every 40 Millis seconds to the database while the millis continuously displayed on the LCD.

Comment: @Blurry Sterk, thanks my dear I tried to add some changes by your solution, but stil I am having the same issue.

Comment: Do you think the cause of this issue is the time consumed to connect to the server and database?

Comment: It is my first guess @Noorallah. For testing this hypothesis instead of connectong to the server in the setup function, you could connect before each query

Comment: @Arton Dorneles, so could you tell me what are the changes should I make?

Comment: @Noorallah, Yes, I included an answer a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

`Millis()` gives you the amount of milliseconds that have passed since the device was power on. It gives you an `unsigned long`. So what happens if the `High` of that `unsigned long` is reached?... It rolls over and starts at zero again (Keep this one in mind).

So, you have a few options to have a milliseconds display that starts from zero;

1. If you use `millis()` then you must have a variable that keeps the very first `millis()` you asked for. Then on each loop get the `millis()` again and deduct the first `millis()` from the latest one. You end up with the actual amount that has passed. The trick is to remember that it can rollover which you must be prepared for.
2. Use a 3rd party library like `elapsedMillis` which actually gives the time elapsed in milliseconds since you initialized the timer to zero. Easy to find via search.

Here is an example of point 1:

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned long FirstMillis;

void setup() {
  // The value assigning you can put wherever you want when you want
  // to start the initialization just remember that you can only 
  // declare the variable once otherwise it will be overwritten each time.
  // Also do not assign on each loop without checking whether it is time
  // to assign 
  FirstMillis = millis();
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long LatestMillis = millis();
  unsigned long TimeElapsed = 0;

  // Check for overflow. I would assume that you will have restarted
  // the timing again before the full range of FirstMillis + ULONG_MAX has been
  // depleted. If so overflow will only happen once. ULONG_MAX
  // in milliseconds is longer than 49 days.
  if (LatestMillis < FirstMillis)
    TimeElapsed = (ULONG_MAX - FirstMillis) + LatestMillis;
  else
    TimeElapsed = LatestMillis - FirstMillis;

 lcd.print(TimeElapsed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL is taking some time to establish a connection, you need to compute the elapsed time only after that. I added a function `elapsedTime` to your code that computes the number of elapsed seconds after a connection is established. If you plan to keep your board on for **more than 49 days** you need to take into account the @Blurry' advice. For additional details about that issue [see this link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=122413.0).

**Updated code:**

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server_addr();  // IP of the MySQL *server* here

char user[] = "";         // MySQL user login username
char password[] = "";     // MySQL user login password

EthernetClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

unsigned long initialTime; 

void setup() {

   // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
   lcd.begin(16, 2);

   // Print a message to the LCD.
   lcd.print("Millis");

   Serial.begin(115200);
   while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect
   Ethernet.begin(mac_addr);
   Serial.println("Connecting...");
   if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)) {
      delay(1000);
   } else {
      Serial.println("Connection failed.");
   }  

   // Initial value of millis() after connection.
   initialTime = millis()/1000;
}

unsigned long elapsedSeconds() {
   return (millis()-initialTime)/1000;
}

void loop() {
   unsigned long var = elapsedSeconds();
   lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
   lcd.print(var);

   if(var%40 == 0) {
      char INSERT_SQL[] = 
          "UPDATE Information.total SET reading=(%d) WHERE Name='Sam';";
      char query[255];
      sprintf(query, INSERT_SQL, var);
      MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
      cur_mem->execute(query);
      delete cur_mem;
   }  
}
```

**Expected output on the LCD:**

Supposing the query in the loop function takes less than one second you should see the following output: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7...`. However, if the query took several seconds, e.g. 10 seconds, you should see an output like `0 10 20 30...` or slightly different. In this case, I would say it is not possible to do what you want using this particular approach.

Comment: @Artlon, thanks for your effort, but still I am getting the same results !! Maybe the are some issues related to the port number or DHCP response.

Comment: @Noorallah, what output did you obtain in the LCD?